# TypeScript: How to create typings for values on a proxy object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get my getter return the proper type of a key in an object. At first I was having my getter return `{ [key: string]: any }` which works but has no types associated to items in the object.

```
class a {

  private static _scope: { [key: string]: any }

  public static get scope(): { [key: string]: typeof key } {
    if(!a._scope){
      a._scope = a.createProxy()
    }
    return a._scope

    // returns a proxy object
    // example:
    // {
    //   a: 999,
    //   b: [1,2,3]
    // }
  }
}

a.scope.a = 999
a.scope.b = [1,2,3]
a.scope.c = 'Spider-Man'
```

So, in the above code what I was hoping to achieve is that when I type `a.scope.a.` it would know that the value was a number. Then when I type `a.scope.b.` it would know that the value was an array.

With what I have in the example above it things that everything is a string, which I understand why. What I don't know (or if it is even possible) is to have it know the type of the value.

Items are added to the object dynamically, so I don't know what keys are in the object or what their types are so using a `type` or `interface` with predefined keys doesn't work that I am aware of.

Comment: Can you give a real life need for something like this?

Comment: I have a library with two-way-binding. Whenever the `scope` changes the proxy tells the the html change `value` or `textContent` if they are listening to `a`, `b`, `c` or whatever is in the scope.

Comment: You could possibly create a type that tracks properties that you add to it, but if they are not known until runtime, I don't see that you can get much tooling.

Answer (score 2):

> Items are added to the object dynamically, so I don't know what keys are in the object or what their types are

In that case there's no way for the compiler to know, either.

You could use a [runtime type system](https://github.com/phadej/typify) (not included in TypeScript) to give you some safety.

But let me press a little against the idea that you "don't know what keys or types" their are ahead of time. In the example you posted you do, in fact, seem to know that `a.scope` should look like `{ a: number; b: number[]; c: string; }`. That's why you're asking the compiler to help you. Maybe that type structure isn't known at the class/instance level, but at some point later it's known, that's why you are writing code against it. This is potentially a good case for [type arguments (aka generics)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Perhaps your example could look like this:

```
class A<TScope> {

    private _scope: TScope;

    public get scope(): TScope {
        if (!this._scope) {
            this._scope = this.createProxy()
        }
        return this._scope;
    }
}

type MyScope = { a: number; b: number[]; c: string; }

const a = new A<MyScope>();

a.scope.a = 999;
a.scope.b = [1, 2, 3];
a.scope.c = 'Spider-Man';
```

Note that I changed the `static` members to instance members so that they can reference the `TScope` class type argument. A static method can't reference a class type parameter, though a static method (not a getter) could take a type argument itself, but then you'd need to pass the type every time you call it:

```
class A {
    public static getScope<T>(): T {
       // ...
    }
}

A.getScope<MyScope>().a = 999;
A.getScope<MyScope>().b = [1, 2, 3];
A.getScope<MyScope>().a = 'Spider-Man';
```

Comment: We don't know that a,b or c exist on the object. those were just examples of values added at run time.

Comment: Then your example is wrong, because you've written code against `a`, `b`, and `c` and expect them to have types `number`, `number[]`, and `string`. Are you iterating over the keys or something?

Comment: in my proxy I have `Proxy.set`, I am able to get the property that changed, then I get a list of items in the dom `querySelectorAll('[data-bind]')`, and if it matches the property, I update the dom element.

Comment: I think you need to update your question with an example of how you are actually using the proxy. As it is currently written it doesn't seem to really reflect your problem.